# Portable c++ standalone executable in eclipse when using cygwin in windows 7

Tags: c++, eclipse, windows-7, cygwin, exe

I have a work machine and a laptop, both running windows 7. For all practical purposes, we can assume that laptop has fresh installation of windows 7 with no programs installed on it.

Now, in my work machine, I am using Eclipse to compile my c++ application using cygwin gcc toolchain. When I build the project, it generates a .exe file in the Debug directory which works fine on the work machine. But the same .exe does not run on my laptop dues to missing dll's.

My question is how can I create standalone executable from my work machine so that I may simply copy the executable to my laptop and it executes successfully. Note that there is no difference in Windows installation in both machines.

I tried to look up the issue on other questions, but their main focus was on creating standalone executable which runs on both windows and linux. Someone suggested the use of artifacts and creating static library but I am not able to gather much information about how to use the generated .a file on my laptop.

Apologies if the question is duplicate, Please paste the link to duplicate(if any) in comments.

Answer (score 0):

It can be because of system architecture, may be your work machine consists of 32-bit processor and laptop consists 64-bit processor or vice-versa.
If this is the problem then you need to convert your compiled application to run in a different architecture.